# How do I pass an auth token through an HTTPCookie in Passport?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-passport

ive been trying to do port my auth from sanctum to passport (specifically, for password grant authentication). the flow works, but i'm hitting a wall when trying to use an httpcookie instead of an authorization header to send the auth token.
heres the middleware i'm using to do this, it overrides `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate`:

```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards) {
    if (!$request->bearerToken()) {
        if ($request->hasCookie("auth_token")) {
            $token = $request->cookie("auth_token");
            $request->headers->set("Authorization", "Bearer " . $token);
        }
    }

    $this->authenticate($request, $guards);
    return $next($request);
}
```

this is registered in `Kernel.php`: `"auth" => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class`, and routes implement it with `auth:api`

ive checked if it actually sets the bearer token before calling `authenticate()` (it works from what i can tell?), but it still returns 401 unauthenticated. also have double checked all of my passport configs, and have searched around for (too many) hours :)

for reference, this is how im setting the httpcookie

```
    $response->withCookie(cookie("auth_token", $token, 1440, null, null, env("APP_DEBUG") ? false : true, true, false, 'Lax'));
    $response->header("access-control-expose-headers", "Set-Cookie");
```

help much appreciated !

EDIT - another interesting piece of info: the line `Auth::guard('api')->check()` unsets the request bearer token when its set from a cookie, but not when its set in a header. this is probably related but I'm not smart enough to piece together a solution.